# What is the Time Complexity for this solution of trimming a message of N length at M length?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to get the correct Time Complexity of my solution for the following question:

```
Input: a string contains spaces and words, and an integer M
Output: trim the string so the trimmed string length <= m and no cut-off word.
Sample:
S = "This is JavaScript", M = 10.
Expect: "This is" // because "This is Ja" is invalid, "JavaScript" is cut. 
S = "JavaScript", M = 5
Expect: "" // empty because the output "JavaS" is invalid.
S = "JavaScript", M = 10
Expect: "JavaScript"
```

Here's my code:

```js
function trimThis(S, M) {
    if (M > S.length) return S;
    let output = S.slice(); // Making a copy of the input is optional
    while (output.length > M) {
        const lastSpaceIdx = output.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (lastSpaceIdx !== -1) {
            const endIdx = Math.min(lastSpaceIdx, output.length);
            output = output.slice(0, endIdx);
        }
        else return '';
    }
    // In JS we can also use trimEnd() to remove trailing spaces:
    while (output.length > 0 && output[output.length - 1] === ' ') {
        output = output.slice(0, -1);
    }
    return output;
}
```

I'm thinking the total Time Complexity is O(N) where n = len(S) but I'm not sure because of the while loop.

The while loop will run O(N - M) times. In each iteration, the code does O(N) operation to find the last space index and the `slice()` operation takes O(N) so it looks like O(N^2). However, after each iteration, the string gets smaller and smaller.

The time to make the copy string O(N) won't affect the overall Big O.

Comment: Please explain your input, output properly. What is cut-off word ?

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity is *O(n²)*, because you perform a `slice` repeatedly, which creates a new string each time. Although the implementation of `slice` is fast, it is not constant in time, but proportional to its length.

You should just work with the index, and just perform the "costly" `slice` at the very end. Note also that the initial slice is not needed as any way strings are immutable. It is not possible to modify *S*, even if you wanted to.

Here is your code adapted to only perform a `slice` at the end. NB: I wouldn't use initial capitals for variable names, as commonly that is reserved for names of constructors.

```js
function trimThis(s, m) {
    let endIdx = s.length;
    while (endIdx > m) {
        lastSpaceIdx = s.lastIndexOf(' ', endIdx - 1);
        if (lastSpaceIdx !== -1) {
            endIdx = lastSpaceIdx;
        } else return '';
    }
    while (endIdx > 0 && s[endIdx - 1] === ' ') {
        endIdx--;
    }
    return s.slice(0, endIdx);
}

let s = "We are living in interesting times";
let res = trimThis(s, 20);
console.log(res);
```

Now it is *O(n)*.

Comment: *"Although the implementation of slice is fast, it is not constant in time, but proportional to its length."* For V8 that's no longer true. [some](https://mrale.ph/blog/2016/11/23/making-less-dart-faster.html) [more](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2869) [info](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9679)

Comment: @Thomas, indeed that is true. As long this is not part of EcmaScript requirements though, we should not rely on it.